# Vistar7 transformer pack 9.04

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I want to install Vistar7 transformer pack9.04.  I've already download Vistar7 setup but I can't understand how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Vistar7 - Windows 7 Transformation Pack](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Vistar7+-+Windows+7+Transformation+Pack?content=104232):

```
Installation:
- make sure you are on-line
- open konsole in Transformation Pack directory
- chmod +x install.sh
- sudo ./install.sh
- login as vistar7 user
```